# Escape special chars in RegEx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a form, that sends the contents of a text field to my Rails application and 
I have to generate a regular expression of this string.

I tried it like this:

```
regex = /#{params[:text]}/
```

In general this is working, but if brackets or special characters are contained in the string, this method will not work.

I don't want Rails to take care of the chars. They should be escaped automatically.

I tried it like this:

```
/\Q#{params[:text]}\E/
```

but this isn't working either.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should use [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape)

```
regex = /#{Regexp.escape(params[:text])}/
# in rails models/controllers with mongoid use:
# ::Regexp.escape(params[:text]) instead. ([more info][2])
```

Answer (score 9):

[`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) escapes special characters:

```
params[:text] = "[foo-bar]"
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(params[:text]))
# => /\[foo\-bar\]/
```